# Website url with multiple names? (myblog.tumblr.com/myweb.webs.com)

Tags: php, mysql, web

How does tumblr create new urls for every user? wouldn't that cost a lot of money? And if not, how is it possible? Would it be done in php, html, or something else. And would it be done through the server?

Answer (score 4):

Subdomains are free.

However these sites typically use wildcard VHosts, accepting requests to `[literally anything goes here].domain.com`. It then uses the `Host` header to determine which subdomain (and therefore whose data) was requested.

Comment: Thanks! I'm starting to learn web development and it's a question that's been bugging me. Hoping to be able to use it for an idea that I've had.